# Can I use libcurls CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION with a C++11 lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, libcurl

I tried to use a C++11 lambda expression with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, but the program crashes at runtime with an access violation. I'm not sure how to look further into this due to lack of C++11 knowledge, but maybe someone else has an idea how to make this work.

The function:

```
#ifndef CURL_GET_H
#define CURL_GET_H

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> curl_get(const char* url)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    std::vector<std::string> content;
    auto curl_callback = [](void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) -> size_t {
        // does nothing at the moment due to testing...
        return size * nmemb;
    };

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/aaa.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return content;
}

#endif // CURL_GET_H
```

The error:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x000000cc in lpip_dl.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung bei Position 0x00000000000000cc.
>
> (Access violation at position 0x00000000000000cc)

Happens when curl wants to use the callback:

```
wrote = data->set.fwrite_func(ptr, 1, len, data->set.out);
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? VC++? If so, VC++ does not support implicit lambda-to-function-pointer conversions (yet?).

Comment: Yes, I'm using VS2010 SP1. I already noticed the other questions covering lambda functions and function pointers but couldn't see the connection to my question. I guess I'll just have to wait for the next VS release :/ The workarounds were quite... confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libcurl is plain C library, you need to set a callback that can be called from a such. This means funny C++ things need to be "C'ified" first to work. Like into an old-style function pointer.

This is also addressed in the libcurl FAQ entry "[Using C++ non-static functions for callbacks?](http://curl.se/docs/faq.html#Using_C_non_static_functions_f)"

See also: [C-style Callbacks in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513380/c-style-callbacks-in-c11)

Answer (score 8):

You actually can do that by casting the lambda function to function pointer. You can first make a typedef to make cast easier.

```
typedef size_t(*CURL_WRITEFUNCTION_PTR)(void*, size_t, size_t, void*);
```

Then you use static_cast.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, static_cast<CURL_WRITEFUNCTION_PTR>(curl_callback));
```

Note: In order to convert to C function pointer, you can only use empty captures [].

Comment: I guess that it is a luckly coincidence that the lambda function class has a function pointer as first and only field.

Comment: Funny. sizeof empty captured lambda function is 1. While sizeof reference captured lambda function is 8.

Comment: I gotta correct myself. I did take a look at the generated assembly. The static_cast is not resolved at compile time, it invokes a function at runtime which "converts" the lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: @AndréPuel All stateless lambda functions have an implicit operator convert-to-function-pointer.  In every compiler with calling convention support I have played with, it even supports convert-to-arbitrary-calling-convention-function-pointer.  You don't even have to cast explicitly, you can just initialize a variable of the appropriate type.  The casting is required because without it, you stick the stateless lambda directly on the stack, not the function pointer the engine expects.  See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513380/c-style-callbacks-in-c11/25533447#25533447]

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with the + prefix, which returns a C-style function pointer instead. But this only works with stateless lambdas (empty capture list i.e. []).

```
auto lambda = +[](void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) -> size_t {
    // does nothing at the moment due to testing...
    return size * nmemb;
};
```

or

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, +[](void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) -> size_t {
    // does nothing at the moment due to testing...
    return size * nmemb;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the lambda to the proper function pointer works for me in Linux:

```
auto curl_callback = static_cast<size_t(*)(char*,size_t,size_t,void*)>([](...){...});
```